# problem of uniform convergence of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The problem is

> Prove that the series 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$$
>   converges uniformly in every bounded interval, but does not converge absolutely for any value of $x$.

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdHiT.png))

My attempt is:

> (a) Let $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $N\in\mathbb{N}\ni \forall n\geq N$,
>   $$\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}<\frac{\epsilon}{2b^2} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$
>   Let $n\geq N$. Then
>   $$\sum_{k=n}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^2+k}{k^2}=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left((-1)^k\frac{x^2}{k^2}+(-1)^k\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\leq\sum_{k=n}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^2}{k^2}+\sum_{k=n}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{1}{k^2}$$
>   $$\leq\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{b^2}{k^2}+\sum_{k=n}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{1}{k^2}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$
>   $$\therefore \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2} \quad\text{converges uniformly on }[a,b]$$
>
> (b) $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}\right|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$$
>   hence the series is not absolutely convergent.

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0h0o.png))

Is my procedure correct?

Thanks for your help

Comment: In your proof of part b, the last inequality should be reversed. Which is OK since $|x^2+n| \ge n$. The part a proof looks right.

Comment: A similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97555/why-does-the-series-sum-k-frac-1kkx2-converge-uniformly-but-not-abso